# How to separate reading and writing in an xml file?

Tags: c#

What is the best way to read and write to an XML file so my writes to not stop my reads? What I would like is two separate classes doing this that are independent and hence to not share locks/mutexes etc.

Currently I am using XDocument.Load() to read the file which I believe takes a lock on the file only on the load.

Comment: You want read/write in to the same file?

Comment: I want to be able to allow multiple readers and multiple writers working on the same file. I know there is a ReadWriterLockSlim() lock and was wondering if there are other ways of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

I would not generally recommend both read/write at the same time but assuming you know the risks, the **read lock** can be removed if you first load the file into memory:

```
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes("myFile");
var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
var doc = XDocument.Load(ms);
```